# HTML5 - building an iPad address bar magnifier with map area highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

I am trying to build an example to highlight multiple image map areas on an html page for the iPad. The idea is similar to the magnifier feature that you notice when you tap and hold the mobile safari address bar. You can pan the magnifier around to go to a particular character. I am trying to leverage the same user experience to highlight image map "poly" areas. When I pan the magnifying glass, I want to scroll through the areas by highlighting them and making them active.

I am thinking of using the Jquery Maphighlight plugin alongwith a CSS/JS magnifier sample
http://persistent.info/files/20040508.magnifier/
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

The place I'm stuck is the actual scrolling between the areas and highlighting them automatically.

I was wondering if anyone has done something similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

Cheers!
Sameer

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite conceptualise what you were wanting, but this may help in any case.

use the pseudo class :active in your css and in the  tag add

In this demo I've simply used CSS transform to simulate the zooming, but it could be replaced with whatever you want.  I think you will find a pure css option faster then any javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/thurstanh/QEudm/5/

```
<body ontouchstart="">
```

css
    img:active {
        -webkit-transform:scale(2,2);
    }

Comment: Thanks for the reply ThorJ, this would definitely help the zooming but my bigger worry is selection of the areas in the area maps while zoomed in. I'm trying to go the canvas way and figure out a solution. Similar to a shooter game.